# Protractor testing with ngStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, ng-storage

I'm using `ngStorage` to deal with local storage and Protractor to e2e specs in an AngularJS app.

```
describe('Test', function() {
  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024)
    browser.get('http://localhost:9000/#/test/first-test')
  })

  it("keeps the alternative marked", function () {
      element(by.id('element')).click()

      browser.refresh()

      expect(element(by.id('element')).isSelected()).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Result:

```
1) Test keeps the alternative marked
   Message:
     Expected false to be true.
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Failed expectation
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (path/spec/test_spec.js:12:52)
```

I think that `browser.refresh()` clears the local storage. Is there a way to keep it or another way to test the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem but I don't think it's related to `browser.refresh()` behaviour. It looks like there are timing issues with `ngStorage` actually updating things in `localStorage`.

You can see in https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js#L205 that `ngStorage` waits for 100ms after a change on $rootScope to actually save to `localStorage`.

What I'm seeing is pretty consistent with this: Sometimes the dismissed item remains hidden after reload, sometimes it doesn't. If I put an explicit `browser.waitForAngular()` before the refresh call, the test passes more often but not every time. The most reliable thing I've found so far is to add an explicit `browser.sleep(125);` after every action that changes `localStorage` via `ngStorage`. Incidentally, this appears to be the method `ngStorage` uses in it's own tests.

Worth noting that the `onbeforeunload` handler in `ngStorage` should take care of this particular case, but appears not to be doing so the correct thing when `browser.refresh()` is called.

Comment: I've added an issue on github to get some better insight about this: https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/issues/226